# position comment-text in front of image in the middle

Tags: css

I have a div `comment-text` that has some text. this text can be any size.

What I want is to align the text in the middle of the image, it is always on top now, I want it in the middle.

Any ideas?

html:

```
<div class="comments">
<div class="pull-left lh-fix">
<img class=foto src="/$foto" class="imgborder">
</div>

<div class="comment-text pull-left">
<span class="pull-left color strong"><a href="/anna">anna</a>:</span> dododod
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.pull-left { float: left; }
.lh-fix { line-height: 0 !important; }

.comments {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-top:8px;
  padding-bottom:8px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}


.comment-text {
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: #333;
  line-height:middle; //not working?
  width: 85%;
  text-align:left;
}

.foto{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jau7Lfqw/

Comment: I can't understand, you said you want the text over the image?

Comment: @ClaudioKing I want to vertically align the text with the image. I want the text to be in front of the image, but in the middle of it, not on top as it is now...

Answer (score 1):

Set `line-height:50px;` to `.comment-text`

**Edit**: (after author comment):

Also it is possible to align center vertically with Flexboxes.

```css
.comments {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-top:8px;
  padding-bottom:8px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}


.comment-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-align:left;
}

.foto{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="comments">
<img class=foto src="/$foto" class="imgborder">

<div class="comment-text">
<span class="color strong"><a href="/anna">anna</a>:</span> long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! it works but with fixed line height it becomes a little ugly when the text is bigger than 50px height. I want it to automatic adjust with text size... if text is big, I want it to fill the div comment-text... I think line-height: middle would to it, but it is not working...